Why does the Gemara in Bava Kamma seemingly ignore the fact that the Melachah is being done with a Shinuy?
The Gemara (Bava Kamma 26b) brings a case where someone had a stone in his lap, and he either forgot or did not realize that it was in his lap, and when he got up the stone was flung out of his lap, and the Gemara says that with regards to the laws of damages he would be liable, but with regards to Shabbos he would be exempt for any Melachah that was caused by the stone.
My question is: with regards to the laws of Shabbos, why does it matter that he forgot or did not realize that he had the stone in his lap - wouldn’t he be exempt even if he did know that it was in his lap, being that the Melachah was done with a Shinuy?

Dayan Padwa addresses this in Ohr Yisroel 3:3 (Nissan 5758), p. 41. (The context is a discussion about a case where one didn't disconnect the refrigerator light before Shabbos, whether he may ask a fellow Jew who doesn't know that to open the refrigerator.)
First he cites R. Akiva Eiger (Teshuvos, no. 8), that the Gemara wanted to make the point that where there's no meleches machsheves (intent to perform the melachah), then by definition there's no melachah at all (unlike if he had been misasek, intending to perform the action but with something where the melachah is inapplicable, where it would be considered a melachah, just an inadvertent (beshogeg) one).
But then R. Padwa goes on to note that in essence, meleches machsheves (or lack thereof) is a broad category that includes misasek, mekalkel (performing a melachah for a destructive purpose) and kil'achar yad (doing the melachah in a non-normal manner, as in your questiopn), so that the Gemara may simply be mentioning that general category.
